# passport.js multiple de/serialize methods

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm building a 2 parts login system. Where the a user will login to a main account `Account` model, this account will hold access to many teams `Team` model, and an account can have 1 user per team `User` model. The problem is that I can define an `Account` login strategy with passport but I will only be able to serialize and deserialize using `Account` model, but when I want to redirect or login the `Account` with their `User` specific data related to a `Team` I can't log them using passport. I need some ideas or solutions, maybe there's some passport strategy out there I could use.
PS: think of this like a slack login system kind of works, main account (email) can hold multiple teams or chat groups with speific details on each.

Comment: Are you now using `passport-local-mongoose` or similar?

Comment: I'm using local statregy (2 registered), but I want to use them with different de/serialize Models

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understood your need correctly I believe you have two options - register multiple (de)serializers, or put more logic into your (de)serialization implementations.

While not really documented, you can register [multiple serialize](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/597e289d6fa27a2c35d16dd411de284123e3817e/lib/authenticator.js#L255-L258) and [deserialize](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/597e289d6fa27a2c35d16dd411de284123e3817e/lib/authenticator.js#L315-L318) functions. If the first function is not successful it should call `done('pass');` to have the execution continue to the next (de)serializer, eg. (note that the code examples are just off the top of my head):

```
passport.deserializeUser((obj, done) => {
  Account.deserialize(obj)
    .then((account) => done(null, account))
    .catch((err) => done('pass'));
});

passport.deserializeUser((obj, done) => {
  User.deserialize(obj).then((user) => done(null, user))
});
```

You are not limited to using the apparently builtin (de)serialization of the ORM/ODM of your choice. Thus you can do any custom logic you need in the serialization functions. For example, put the model instance ID and type into an object in serialization, and use them when deserializing.

```
passport.serializeUser((obj, done) => {
  if (obj instanceof Account) {
    done(null, { id: obj.id, type: 'Account' });
  } else {
    done(null, { id: obj.id, type: 'User' });
  }
});

passport.deserializeUser((obj, done) => {
  if (obj.type === 'Account') {
    Account.get(obj.id).then((account) => done(null, account));
  } else {
    User.get(obj.id).then((user) => done(null, user));
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks you just enlighten me, I'm going to try this over the course of the coming days and let you know, thanks i think this is potentially the answer.

Comment: I am facing the same issue using passport-local-mongoose , someone can help ?