# passport-local-mongoose and Google Auth, how handle mutltiple serializers with Passport.js?

Tags: node.js, passport.js

how to handle provider strategy and local strategy with passport.js using passport-local-mongoose?

Here I am defining my strategies and de/serializers

```
// For my Local strategy 
passport.serializeUser(Admin.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(Admin.deserializeUser());

// For my Google strategy 
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id); //user.id is the id from Mongo
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  User.findById(id).then(user => {
    done(null, user);
  });
});

passport.use('google',
new GoogleStrategy(
{
  clientID: keys.googleClientID,
  clientSecret: keys.googleClientSecret,
  callbackURL: "/auth/google/callback",
  proxy: true
},
async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
  const existingUser = await User.findOne({ googleId: profile.id });

  if (existingUser) { 
    done(null, existingUser);
  } else {
    const user = await new User({ googleId: profile.id, token: accessToken, name:profile.displayName }).save();
    done(null, user);
    }
  }
 )
);

passport.use('local', new LocalStrategy(Admin.authenticate()));
```

Like you see I have 2 de/serializers and this is  a problem and that is not working but if I take just one serializer and one deserializer for each strategy that is working
so the question is how to handle Local and Google strategy with Passport.Js and node.js

This what I am trying to do

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  if(// This is Local Strategy){

    User.serializeUser();
}
else{

    done(null, user);
}
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user,id, done) {
    if(// This is Local Strategy){

        User.serializeUser();
}
    else{

       User.findById(id).then(user => {
           done(null, user);
        });
    }
});
```

UPDATE : 
I found a post [passport.js multiple de/serialize methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45897332/passport-js-multiple-de-serialize-methods/45924232#45924232) with more information about multiple de/serializers and I tried this :

```
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id); //user.id is the id from Mongo
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    User.findById(id)
        .then(user => {done(null, user)
         // .catch((err) => done('pass'));
        });
});

passport.deserializeUser((obj, done) => {
    Admin.deserializeUser();
});
```

But the catch block mentioned in this post not working for me

Comment: Move the `catch` outside the `then` `User.findById(id).then(user => {
    done(null, user)
}).catch((err) => done('pass'))`

Comment: what about serializers? how can I use multiple serializers

Answer (score 0):

From your update:

```
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id); //user.id is the id from Mongo
});


passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    User.findById(id)
        .then(user => {
             done(null, user)
        })
        .catch((err) => done('pass')); //you should use catch like this
});

passport.deserializeUser((obj, done) => {
    Admin.deserializeUser();
});
```

If it still does not work, 
Follow my code: [passport config](https://pastebin.com/TBRD9c7V)